# Update PostgreSQL version to 13 in TravisCI

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci, mojolicious

I have some issues with the TravisCI platform when I try to test the code when Pull Requesting some changes. It works fine so far, but now I get this warning in the build-run log when I run the `travis_apt_get_update` command:

> The PostgreSQL version 9.4 is obsolete, but the server or client packages
> are still installed. Please install the latest packages (postgresql-13 and
> postgresql-client-13) and upgrade the existing  clusters with
> pg_upgradecluster (see manpage).

I have added the `postgresql-13` and `postgresql-client-13` packages, here is the `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: perl
perl:
  - "5.30"
dist: xenial
env:
  - HOST_URL="localhost"
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/path/to/local
services:
  - postgresql
addons:
  postgresql: 13
  apt:
    packages:
    - postgresql-13
    - postgresql-client-13
    - libpq-dev
    - build-essential
    - libssl-dev
    - zlib1g-dev
    - clang-tidy
env:
  global:
    - PGPORT=5433
before_install:
  - wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/astyle/astyle_3.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
  - sudo dpkg -i astyle_3.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
  - sudo chmod -R 777 /var/log/
```

Now, in the log it says that I have to upgrade the clusters with `pg_upgradecluster`, but I really don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

This example (`.travis.yml`) shows how to run Postgres13 within your Ubuntu jobs. You can configure/add additional configuration as your setup and see if that helps.

```
---
dist: focal
language: ruby

addons:
  postgresql: '13'
  apt:
      packages:
        - postgresql-13
env:
  global:
   - PGUSER=postgres
   - PGPORT=5432
   - PGHOST=localhost
before_install:
 - sudo sed -i -e '/local.*peer/s/postgres/all/' -e 's/peer\|md5/trust/g' /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf
 - sudo service postgresql restart
 - sleep 1
 - postgres --version

script:
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Thanks.